# Is my snake plant dying or is this normal?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, soil, dryness, snake-plants

[image]
[image]

Not sure if this is normal for leaves to die or if it's something else? I repotted this a few months ago and it's generally been doing okay I think, and even has a new growth. However a few weeks ago two of the leaves started to turn yellow. Another one has a dry patch that seems to be spreading. Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there drainage holes in the pot?

Comment: Yes there are and I don't water too frequently!